# Does the order in which qubits are measured matter in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-computing

I’ll define my question more specifically:

Lets suppose we have an $n$ bit quantum computer, with qubits labelled $q_{1},…,q_{n}$, and let $b$ be any bit string of length $n$ (let’s assume we’ve labelled each qubits’ states $0$ and $1$ so that we obtain an $n$ bit bit string when we measure the qubits).

The question is, is the probability that we obtain $b$ when we measure each qubits’ state dependent on the order in which we measure the qubits? 
I have a feeling the probability would be independent of the order the qubits are measured, but am struggling to prove this.

Comment: Consider the case where we take the qubits one light year apart, measure them in close succession, and then bring them back together

Comment: @JanDvorak How could measuring the qubits when they're 1 light year apart and then bringing them back together alter the probabilities (of obtaining each measurement outcome), from the case where qubits are close together (as they would be in a quantum computer)?

Comment: It's an axiom of quantum mechanics that space-like separated measurements commute (otherwise you'd be getting different results depending on your frame of reference). If your measurements can be space-like separated, they commute.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is a little above my understanding of Quantum Physics (I'm a Computer Scientist studying Quantum Computing :) )

Comment: Have you tried proving this using the definitions? That's always a good start.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I can see for the case where the qubits are not entangled that the order wouldn't matter, but for the case when they are entangled I can't as I'm not sure on the following issue: Lets suppose qubits $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are entangled. Then I know that if we measure $q_{1}$, that $q_{2}$'s superposition state will collapse, but I'm not sure on what the probability that $q_{2}$ will take $0$ or $1$ is - does it depend on the state $q_{1}$ took at all when measured, or is it just dependent on $q_{2}$'s superposition state at the time $q_{1}$ was measured

Comment: Try using formulas for the probability to compute the probability (or rather, density) of getting a certain outcome when you measure the bits in the order $q_1,q_2$. You should get something symmetric in the indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the order doesn't matter.

**Proofs**

- *Algebra*. Take an input state $\sum_k c_k |k_0 k_1 k_2 ...\rangle$. Apply the definition of measurement from your textbook to it. Compute the expression for the probabilities and outputs of each case when measuring qubit 0 then qubit 1. Do the same for measuring qubit 1 then qubit 0. Notice that the two expressions are equal. Generalize.
- *Circuit moves.* Measurement is equivalent to a CNOT gate from the target qubit onto an ancilla qubit that you simply don't use for anything else:

  [image: measure as cnot]

  So if you think you can change the outcome statistics by reordering measurements, you should think you can do the same without involving measurements at all (until a simultaneous measurement of all qubits at the end of the circuit). All you should need is independent CNOTs. But clearly independent CNOTs can be re-ordered.
- *Play*. For me, the fact that ordering doesn't matter wasn't proven so much as experienced. I [dragged gates around in Quirk](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5Et%22%2C%22X%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%5D%7D) and noticed that measurement is easily the most boring operation. All measurement does is throw away off-diagonal density matrix elements. Even for the *target* qubit, measurement doesn't change the computational basis probabilities.